# Calculate current video time with FFMPEG

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

Currently we tried using `AVCodecContext->frame_number/fps` to get the current time of the video, but this variable seem to only go up, so after a backward seek the calculated time is all messed up.

Can AVCodecContext->frame_number be used for this purpose? If so, how should it be used; if not, what then is the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AVStream [duration](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVStream.html) field to get full video length.
And here is an  [example](http://svn.gnumonks.org/tags/21c3-video/upstream/ffmpeg-0.4.9-pre1/output_example.c) how to get current video time.